# Cisco ASA double NAT with DNS translation

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, nat, dns

I'm trying to set up double Auto NAT with DNS translation on Cisco ASA 9.0(3), and I'm having a few challenges with the DNS portion.  I got double NAT working correctly, such that I have a server in production and in the lab with the same IP address.  See b2masd1, nameif INSIDE (production) and masd1, nameif DMZ (lab).

When you ping from DMZ 10.195.18.182 to 1.195.18.182, I see the translations happening correctly in both directions...

```
D:10.195.18.182      S:192.168.11.101       D:1.195.18.182   S:10.195.18.182
             <-----------                         <-----------
                                           1) echo-request to 1.195.18.182
                                           nat (INSIDE,DMZ) static 1.195.18.182 dns



  S:10.195.18.182    D:192.168.11.101       S:1.195.18.182   D:10.195.18.182
              ------------>                        ------------>
      2) echo-reply to 192.168.11.101
      nat (DMZ,INSIDE) static 192.168.11.101 dns


 b2masd1                   +-----------+              masd1
 10.195.18.182      INSIDE |           | DMZ          10.195.18.182
 Mfg Server   -------------| Cisco ASA |------------  Devel Server
                           |           |
                           +-----------+

 Manufacturing                                        Development
 Network                                              Network
 Security: 100                                        Security: 50
```

This is what I see on masd1...

```
masd1$ /usr/sbin/ping 1.195.18.182
PING 1.195.18.182: 64 byte packets
64 bytes from 1.195.18.182: icmp_seq=0. time=0. ms
64 bytes from 1.195.18.182: icmp_seq=1. time=0. ms

----1.195.18.182 PING Statistics----
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 0/0/0
masd1$
```

The problem is that DNS queries from the DMZ to INSIDE are *not* getting translated.  When I query for b2masd1 from the DMZ, I expect the nameserver on the INSIDE to respond with 10.195.18.182, and then the ASA should translate that to 1.195.18.182.  However, that is not happening; as you can see, the DNS entry is not translated.

```
masd1$ nslookup
Using /etc/hosts on:  masd1

> a2mosd1
Using /etc/hosts on:  masd1

looking up FILES
Trying DNS
Name:    b2masd1.domain.local
Address:  10.195.18.182

> exit
masd1$
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get DNS queries correctly translated?  I need a query for b2masd1 in the DMZ to a nameserver on the INSIDE interface to return 1.195.18.182 (because the ASA translates the INSIDE A-Record 10.195.18.182 to DMZ addr 1.195.18.182).

I have set up a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11647/cisco-asa-double-nat-with-dns-translation) to assist with diagnosis

---

*Misc debugging information*

This is my config...

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.195.2.197 255.255.255.248 standby 10.195.2.198
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif DMZ
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.195.2.201 255.255.255.248 standby 10.195.2.202
!
object network DMZ_NAT_masd1
 host 10.195.18.182
 description xlate masd1 NAT DMZ src 10.195.18.182 to INSIDE src 192.168.11.101
object network INSIDE_NAT_masd1
 host 10.195.18.182
 description xlate masd1 NAT INSIDE src 10.195.18.182 to DMZ src 1.195.18.182
!
object network DMZ_NAT_masd1
 nat (DMZ,INSIDE) static 192.168.11.101 dns
object network INSIDE_NAT_masd1
 nat (INSIDE,DMZ) static 1.195.18.182 dns
!
policy-map type inspect dns DNS_INSPECT_MAP
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns DNS_INSPECT_MAP
!
service-policy global_policy global
```

Show xlate, in case this helps...

```
B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT# sh xlate local 10.195.18.182
121 in use, 126 most used
Flags: D - DNS, e - extended, I - identity, i - dynamic, r - portmap,
       s - static, T - twice, N - net-to-net
NAT from DMZ:10.195.18.182 to INSIDE:192.168.11.101
    flags sD idle 0:00:01 timeout 0:00:00
NAT from INSIDE:10.195.18.182 to DMZ:1.195.18.182
    flags sD idle 0:03:55 timeout 0:00:00
B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT#
```

Show service-policy inspect dns...

```
B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT# sh service-policy inspect dns

Global policy:
  Service-policy: global_policy
    Class-map: inspection_default
      Inspect: dns DNS_INSPECT_MAP, packet 15302, drop 0, reset-drop 0, v6-fail-close 0
        message-length maximum 512, drop 0
        dns-guard, count 7649
        protocol-enforcement, drop 0
        nat-rewrite, count 139
B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT#
```

Captures showing queries from b2masd1 to the name server (10.195.18.201).  NOTE the double DNS queries sent on the INSIDE interface, but we don't seem to get those on the DMZ interface.

```
B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT# capture FOO interface DMZ real-time match udp host 10.195.18.182 host 10.195.18.201

Warning: using this option with a slow console connection may
         result in an excessive amount of non-displayed packets
         due to performance limitations.

Use ctrl-c to terminate real-time capture


   1: 09:54:35.994730       10.195.18.182.52639 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 45
   2: 09:54:35.995218       10.195.18.201.53 > 10.195.18.182.52639:  udp 83
   3: 09:54:47.875076       10.195.18.182.52644 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 53
   4: 09:54:47.875549       10.195.18.201.53 > 10.195.18.182.52644:  udp 136
   5: 09:54:47.875854       10.195.18.182.52645 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 51
   6: 09:54:47.876297       10.195.18.201.53 > 10.195.18.182.52645:  udp 138
   7: 09:54:47.876648       10.195.18.182.52646 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 35
   8: 09:54:47.877075       10.195.18.201.53 > 10.195.18.182.52646:  udp 35

B2-DEV-FW1/DEVELOPMENT# capture FOO interface INSIDE real-time match udp host 192.168.11.101 host 10.195.18.201

Warning: using this option with a slow console connection may
         result in an excessive amount of non-displayed packets
         due to performance limitations.

Use ctrl-c to terminate real-time capture


   1: 09:56:27.282608       10.195.18.182.52742 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 43
   2: 09:56:27.282684       192.168.11.101.52742 > 10.195.18.201.53:  udp 43
   3: 09:56:27.283081       10.195.18.201.53 > 192.168.11.101.52742:  udp 59
   4: 09:56:27.283096       10.195.18.201.53 > 10.195.18.182.52742:  udp 59
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question to help future googlers.  I spent about 3 hours on the phone with TAC; we finally got to the root cause of the issue.

The solution is to add a special NAT entry, which matches the IP address in the DNS A-Record when it arrives on the INSIDE interface.

```
object network DNS_NAT_masd1
 description xlate A-Record DMZ src 1.195.18.182 to INSIDE src 10.195.18.182
 host 1.195.18.182
 nat (DMZ,INSIDE) static 10.195.18.182
```

When I asked for a pointer to documentation that describes why DNS translation works this way, the TAC lead said that he didn't know of any that described this behavior.  The TAC lead also mentioned that with more code, the ASA would know to automatically translate the DNS A-Record without explicitly adding `object network DNS_NAT_masd1`; however, that is not how the `dns` keyword for ASA NAT works today.  For reasons that still are not completely clear yet, the ASA requires the DNS A-Record IP to match the `<proxy_addr>` in the NAT statement, using syntax similar to this...

```
object network obj-EXAMPLE
 description NAT object explicitly for translating DNS A-Records
 host <proxy_addr>
 nat (<REAL_INTF>,<PROXY_INTF>) static <real_addr> dns
```

The difficulty is that this configuration is exactly backwards for what you need to do if you're going to nat regular "data plane" IP traffic through the firewall.

This is the whole configuration that works...

```
object network DMZ_NAT_masd1
 host 10.195.18.182
 description xlate masd1 NAT DMZ src 10.195.18.182 to INSIDE src 192.168.11.101
object network INSIDE_NAT_masd1
 host 10.195.18.182
 description xlate masd1 NAT INSIDE src 10.195.18.182 to DMZ src 1.195.18.182
!!! DNS_NAT_masd1 is new
object network DNS_NAT_masd1
 host 1.195.18.182
 description xlate A-Record DMZ src 1.195.18.182 to INSIDE src 10.195.18.182
!
object network DMZ_NAT_masd1
 nat (DMZ,INSIDE) static 192.168.11.101
object network INSIDE_NAT_masd1
 nat (INSIDE,DMZ) static 1.195.18.182
!!! DNS_NAT_masd1 is new
object network DNS_NAT_masd1
 nat (DMZ,INSIDE) static 10.195.18.182 dns
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike!  Thank you for sharing this!
I used this workaround with twice NAT, and it works also!

I have twice NAT  (ASA OS v 9.5):

nat (outside,inside) source dynamic ANY X destination GroupM GroupN

So, I have group of servers "GroupN" on my inside and I NAT them to outside to IP addresses "GroupM". Clients from outside (any) can access my servers and when external clients go through ASA their sources are replaced to IP address X.

Here isn't possible to use dns  keyword. But with your workaround I've created set of auxiliary object NATs:

```
object network My_Server1_on_Inside
 host <NATed IP of Server1>
 nat (outside,inside) static <Real IP of server1> dns
```

AND I've got DNS doctoring working correctly.

BTW, Cisco in it's documentation says that this task is impossible :)
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/115753-dns-doctoring-asa-config.html

Best Regards,
Sergey